# append lines from files to another files

Tags: linux, shell

I would like to append lines from file1 to file2 , the trick is each line from file1 when we append it to files2 it should goes to same line number

exmaple file 1

```
/var/2019/7/10/1266941.mp3
 /var/2019/7/10/1266941.mp3
 /var/2019/7/10/1266941.mp3
```

exmaple file  2

```
1266941
1266941
1266941
```

New file lines should be

```
/var/2019/7/10/1266941.mp3  1266941
 /var/2019/7/10/1266941.mp3  1266941
 /var/2019/7/10/1266941.mp3 1266941
```

what is the best way to do it

Answer (score 0):

```sh
paste file1 file2
```

is probably what you are looking for.